# What is the difference between adding capacitor in 2 different ways to create the delay?

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor, analog, ltspice, delay

I’m finding similar delay results for both the circuits shown below.

Draft 1: Capacitor C3 and C1 are connected to separate branches, though both of them together determine effective delay.

Draft 2: Capacitor C1 = single capacitance whose value is same as equivalent of Draft 1.

Draft 2 schematic seems to be the straightforward solution.

Is there any reason why/where Draft 1 schematic is preferred?

[image]

Comment: Draft1 has a slight bit of negative feedback and maybe the designer wanted this.

Comment: @Andy: Sorry, how exactly is C3 helping the -ve feedback? As long as VCC is  stable, any other voltage changes in C3 should not affect, the -ve feedback, right?

Comment: The Vcc has a resistor in series.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get the -ve feedback occurrence.